# Streaming live from Rio

Tags: pattern, knowledge, language, geography

> Check out this list of destinations I compiled for my vacation. The content of the list is still a bit fluid, but the ordering should be correct now.
>
> 1. Rio de Janeiro, Brazil
> 2. Baghdad, Iraq
> 3. ???, Quebec, Canada
> 4. Chengdu, Sichuan, China
> 5. Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan
> 6. ???, California, USA

Can you figure out the missing places?

Hint:

> The order is important.

Hint #2:

> #2 is located in an important historical region.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You make hard riddles, jafe.

So I think it has something to do with...

> **rivers**. Which would make sense given the title.

**Rio de Janeiro**:

> Rio = river in Portuguese. Just **one river** here.

**Baghdad**:

> Is in Iraq which was in Mesopotamia (thanks, second clue!), which means "between **two rivers**".

**Chengdu**:

> Sichuan means "**four river** circuits" (old Chinese administrative division).

**Lahore**:

> Punjab is the "land of **five rivers**" in Punjabi.

So after much consideration, I'd say the missing locations are...

> [Trois-Rivières, Quebec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trois-Rivi%C3%A8res) and [Six Rivers National Forest in California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Rivers_National_Forest)

Comment: All correct. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The answers are:

> **QUEBEC CITY** and **SACRAMENTO**

Reason:

> *Rio de Janeiro* is the most well known city of *Brazil*.
>  *Baghdad* is the capital city of *Iraq*.
>  *Chengdu* is the capital city of *Sichuan, China*.
>  *Lahore* is the capital city of *Punjab, Pakistan*.
>  Therefore, the others should be the capitals of the given place names.

Comment: The capital city of Brazil is Brasilia.

Comment: Lahore is the capital city of Punjab, Pakistan.. not INDIA..